# Salesforce Email Template Merge Fields for Related Object

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom OBject (CusObj__c) which having 2 lookup fields(Author and Modifier) with users Module. I am having a requirement that when record will get created in CusObj__c, an email should get trigger and email content should show email address of the Auther and Modifier.
I am trying the below code but its is not working

```
{!CusObj__c.Author__r.Email}
{!CusObj__c.Modifier__r.Email}
```

Please suggest

Comment: You used `__c` for `CusObj__c` and `__r` for Author and Modifier. Did you already try `CusObj__r`?

Comment: no i didnt try CusObj__r, So what should i use {!CusObj__r.Modifier__r.Email}?

Comment: I would give it a shot!

Comment: Actually, it looks like this is not supported. There is an idea to allow it that never got added to the platform. I think the conventional wisdom here is to just make a formula field on `CusObj__c` that contains this lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Abraham suggested - you could make a formula field for that on your object. It's bit wasteful if it's just for one email...

Or you could try making a Visualforce email template. It'll let you go "up" the relation up to 5 times.

Something like this?

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="User" relatedToType="CusObj__c" subject="hi stackoverflow">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody>
        <html>
            <body>
            <p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>
            <p>Here's your stuff: {!relatedTo.Modifier__r.Email}</p>
            </body>
        </html>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```